# adobe flash cs6 actionscript 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

anyone can help me about on how to make save and load the current scene using adobe flash cs6 actionscript 2.0?

```
var savefile = SharedObject.getLocal("nameOfTheGame");
```

for save

```
on (press){
savefile.data.levelNumber=_root.level;
savefile.data.anything=_root.anything;
savefile.flush();
```

for load

```
on (press){
  if(savefile.data.levelNumber==undefined){
    _root.levelNumber=1;//the level will equal 1>}
  else{
    _root.level=savefile.data.levelNumber; saved
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your current code ?

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to save the current scene..and when you press load button..the last scene will appear..can you give me example of that?thanks..

Comment: I know that there is a AS3 property of a MovieClip which is [`currentScene`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentScene) to get the current scene but I don't think that there is something like that in AS2, but instead you can use a var to store your current scene and save it to your SO and then load it to go to the last user's scene. And may be it's a time to [try to pass to AS3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html) !